# Using R sqlQuery() in Azure Databricks

Tags: r, sql-server, azure, databricks

I am currently investigating the implications of running our local R and SQL scripts in Azure Databricks.

In our local environment I have an R script, in this script I create an ODBC-connection to a SQL Server Database. Using this connection I call local separate SQL scripts.

```
library(doBy)
library(RODBC)
channel1 <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:SQLSERVER,1433;Uid=ADMIN;Pwd=PASSWORD;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;database=DB;")

filename <- "CREATE_TABLE_X.sql"
sqlcontent <- readChar(filename,nchars=file.info(filename)$size)

sqlQuery(channel1, sqlcontent, errors=TRUE, believeNRows=FALSE)
```

The above query fails when executing readChar() it is unable to locate the file. Also when I copy the notebook file path I receive the same error. To me this seems strange, if I use the following command it can locate the notebook:

```
%python
dbutils.notebook.run("CREATE_TABLE_X.sql",60)
```

The only difference being that I'm locating the Notebook using Python. Other than using another language the problem with this is also that it's not using the connection.

I suspect I'm not using Databricks in the appropriate way, so if you have any general suggestions please let me know. Other than that I would like to understand why I am unable to locate my notebook SQL script using R and what is the recommended route.

Thanks a bunch in advance! :)

Comment: Is `"CREATE*.sql"` found by `list.files()`? If that doesn't see the file either, `readChar` won't work. How does `dbutils.notebook` know where to look in the azure presence for it? Base R isn't going to know that.

Comment: You need to put file onto DBFS and refer to it as `/dbfs/...path_on_dbfs`. `dbutils.notebook.run` works with notebooks that aren't files

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. I will try and your suggestions and get back to you :)

Comment: I implemented the above solution by uploading the SQL file manually to the DBFS. This doesn't seem like the scalable solution so next week I will try and figure out a way to programmatically add the sql files to the dbfs. Enjoy your weekend!